# If more than 1 image file exists in Laravel Model

Tags: laravel, model, return, assets, file-exists

I found out that im unable to use assets in file_exists if i put them in the controller, thats why im using them inside the model. Anyway in my code i need to output 3 different pictures if each of them are available.

This is my current code

```
if(File::exists( public_path().'/image/hospitals/' .$this->HospitalID . '.jpg')){
            return asset('/image/hospitals/' .$this->HospitalID . '.jpg');
        }  else {
            return asset('/image/hospitals/default.jpg');
        }
```

For now this code is only able to output 1 image and default it if the image is not available. My question is, how do I input 3 images? 
My file names for the 3 images are:

[HospitalID]_1.jpg [HospitalID_2].jpg [HospitalID_3].jpg

for example 
10_1.jpg 10_2.jpg 10_3.jpg

thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in your object, that might be Hostpital, you store those file names or ids, so you could just return an array of IDs or even simpler, return the hospital object, then in your controller you should do something like:

```php
class HospitalController extends Controller {
    // some code
    public function method_name($id) {
        $hospital = Hospital::find($id);
        // some other stuff
        return view('name_of_view')->withHospital($hospital);
}
```

Then in your view you could do:

```php
        @foreach ($hospital->images as $image_id)
        <img src={{ public_path() . '/image/hospitals/' . $image_id ".jpg" }} />
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Hi, this one works too, but i end up using 3 functions for 3 different pictures and it works well too.. sorry for the late reply and thanks for your time!